# javascript works but contact form still sends mail

Tags: javascript, html, email, contacts

Hi and sorry for my bad English

I have a contact page and i am using javascript to make a "captcha". so peaople must make a math and if thats correct they can send me a e-mail. Now my problem is that javasctipt give a alert that the math is wrong or not filled but the e-mail is still seended.

my html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function validate () {
    var ta = document.getElementById("ta").value;
    var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    var digit1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit1").innerHTML);
    var digit2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit2").innerHTML);
    var sum = digit1+ digit2;
    if (answer === null || answer === "") {
    alert("reken de cijfers uit");
    return false;
    } else if (answer != sum){
    alert("je som is fout");
    } else if (ta === null || ta === ""){
    alert("schrijf een bericht");
    } else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "bezig met sturen";
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "";
    }
}

function randNums () {
    var rand_num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;
    var rand_num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;
    document.getElementById("digit1") .innerHTML=rand_num1;
    document.getElementById("digit2") .innerHTML=rand_num2;
}

</script>

<body onload="randNums() ;">

<form action="/cgi-bin/form.cgi" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate ();">
<input type="hidden" name="DEBUG" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="MAILFILE" value="peymankarimi/form/sjabloon.txt">
<input type="hidden" name="MAILTO" value="peyman_50@hotmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="REPLYFAULT" value="peymankarimi/form/formulier.html">
<input type="hidden" name="REPLYOK" value="peymankarimi/form/verzonden.html">

<table border="0" width="374" id="contactformulier">
<tr>
    <td width="137">Naam:</td>
    <td width="230"><input type="text"  size="31" name="naam" placeholder="Naam"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="137">Voornaam:</td>
    <td width="230"><input type="text" size="31" name="voornaam" placeholder="Voornaam"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="137">Woonplaats:</td>
    <td width="230"><input type="text" size="31" name="woonplaats" placeholder="Woonplaats"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="137">Telefoonnummer:</td>
    <td width="230"><input type="text" size="31" name="telefoon" placeholder="Telefoonnummer">    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="137">E-mailadres: <br></br></td>
    <td width="230">
    <input type="text" size="31" name="MAILFROM" placeholder="E-mailadres"> <br></br> </td>
</tr>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td width="137">Onderwerp:</td>
    <td width="230"><input type="text" size="31" maxlength="30" name="SUBJECT"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2">Uw vragen, opmerkingen, suggesties, ... :<br>
    <textarea id="ta" name="omschrijving" rows="6" cols="43" ></textarea>
    <br />
    <strong> Tel deze cijfers op </strong>
<span id="digit1"> </span> +
<span id="digit2"> </span> =
<input type="text" id="answer" size="2"; />
<br /> 
<p align="right"><input type="submit" name="cmdVerzenden" value="Verzenden">&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" name="cmdWissen" value="Wissen"></td>
</form>

</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: my site: http://users.telenet.be/peymankarimi/contact.html

Comment: You should show the php as well mate.

Comment: I dont use php because telenet my provider dont support php...

Comment: Your `validate` function doesn't always return something to the form `onsubmit` event handler.  Also, anything that you want to block by using this catchpa will just bypass it completely and submit the form anyway.

Comment: @Darren It has NOTHING to do with the server

Comment: @epascarello calm down mate, I missed the hidden input fields with his mailing stuff. I wasn't talking about the server either...? (Assumed emailing through php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validate function needs to return false on all errors to stop the form from submitting. You only seem to have it for one error.

```
function validate () {
    var ta = document.getElementById("ta").value;
    var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    var digit1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit1").innerHTML);
    var digit2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit2").innerHTML);
    var sum = digit1+ digit2;
    if (answer === null || answer === "") {
    alert("reken de cijfers uit");
    return false;
    } else if (answer != sum){
    alert("je som is fout");
    return false;
    } else if (ta === null || ta === ""){
    alert("schrijf een bericht");
    return false;
    } else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "bezig met sturen";
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i do that cuz its my first time using javascript